# is there an interest to test basic incrementation in a unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Is there an interest to test basic incrementation with a unit test ?

**Method in test class**

```
@Test
public void testIncreaseString() throws Exception {

}
```

**Method in original class**

```
public void increaseString() {
    counterString++;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method is public and it performs a logic, so it makes sense to test it.

Nevertheless, this method

```
public void increaseString() {
    counterString++;
}
```

doesn't return result. So to test the behavior of this method you should check the side-effect resulted of this method.

For example if you have a method `String getCounter()` that returns the value of `counterString` you could use this method to make the assertion.

Comment: `counterString` cannot be a string, since `String` doesn't support the increment operator. I would guess that `counterString` is an `int`.